# How to read out File for every Fragment in a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented a NavigationDrawer and want to read out a specific xml-File for each item in the navigation. The names of the files (except the '.xml') are the same as the titles of the navigation list. 
For the Fragment I tried this code

```
public class VpFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String FRAGMENT_NUMBER = "fragment_number";

    public VpFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vp, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(FRAGMENT_NUMBER);
        String tag = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vpList_array)[i];
        String filename = tag+".xml";
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis=null;
        try {
            fis = getActivity().openFileInput(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {
            while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
                fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        TextView eingabe = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showDay);
        eingabe.setText(tag + fileContent);

        return rootView;
    } 
}
```

But this causes the error
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app/my.app.Vertretungsplaene}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I think it is strange that the whole code works if I replace the code

```
String filename = tag+".xml";
```

by

```
String filename = "filename.xml";
```

Does anyone know the problem or can help me?

Thank you from Germany

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger? Are you sure that the `filename` variable does end up with the same value as `"filename.xml"` when you read the tag variable?

Comment: Thank you. I saved the files with lower cases instead of the first upper letter.